# Subtract column data from two unrelated tables

Tags: sql-server, ssms

[image]

> this is my database diagram i want to determine blood remaining in each bank i am having a problem because the tables donation and transfusion are not related how i can subtract?
>
> i have created two selections of blood drawn and blood withdrawn from each bank now i need to subtract but i don't know how

[image]

Comment: Please you should try to avoid images if possible, copy and paste your queries as text and use some web site like [this](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) to generate text tables. Have a look at this question on how to generate a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example)

Answer (score 2):

Please, next time when adding a question, add the table create scripts, and some sample data. This saves a lot of time for both the person asking the question, and the person answering it.

One way to do this can do this with CTE's:

**Table Structure and sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[Donation Record]([Donation ID] INT ,  [Blood bank name] NVARCHAR(255) ,[Donation] DATETIME)
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[Donation]([Donation ID] INT, [Donor ID] INT, [Amount Donated] INT)

CREATE TABLE [DBO].[Transfusion Record] ([Transfusion ID] INT ,  [Blood bank name] NVARCHAR(255) ,[Transfusion] DATETIME)
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[Transfusion]([Transfusion ID] INT, [Patient ID] INT, [Amount Accepted] INT)


INSERT INTO  [DBO].[Donation Record]([Donation ID],[Blood bank name])
VALUES(1,'California Blood Center'), 
      (2,'Community Blood bank'),
      (3,'Delta Blood bank'),
      (4,'Houchin Valley Blood bank')

INSERT INTO [DBO].[Donation]([Donation ID],[Donor ID],[Amount Donated])
VALUES(1,1,510),(2,2,501),(3,3,353),(3,4,500),(3,5,500),(4,6,323),(4,6,700)



INSERT INTO  [DBO].[Transfusion Record]([Transfusion ID],[Blood bank name])
VALUES(1,'California Blood Center'), 
      (2,'Community Blood bank'),
      (3,'Delta Blood bank'),
      (4,'Houchin Valley Blood bank')

INSERT INTO [DBO].[Transfusion]([Transfusion ID],[Patient ID],[Amount Accepted])
VALUES(1,1,488),(2,2,212),(3,3,300),(3,4,519),(4,6,300),(4,6,444)
```

**Original Query's**

```
SELECT dr.[Blood bank name], COUNT(dr.[Donation ID]) as 'number of donations', sum(d.[Amount Donated]) as 'blood drawn'

FROM [DBO].[Donation Record] as dr JOIN  [Donation] as d on dr.[Donation ID] = d.[Donation ID]
group by dr.[Blood bank name]


SELECT tr.[Blood bank name], COUNT(t.[Transfusion ID]) as 'number of donations', sum(t.[Amount Accepted]) as 'blood drawn'

FROM [DBO].[Transfusion Record] as tr JOIN  [Transfusion] as t on tr.[Transfusion ID] = t.[Transfusion ID]
group by tr.[Blood bank name]
```

**Solution with CTE's to subtract:**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT dr.[Blood bank name], COUNT(dr.[Donation ID]) as 'number of donations', sum(d.[Amount Donated]) as 'blood drawn'

FROM [DBO].[Donation Record] as dr JOIN  [Donation] as d on dr.[Donation ID] = d.[Donation ID]
group by dr.[Blood bank name]
),
CTE2 AS(
SELECT tr.[Blood bank name], COUNT(t.[Transfusion ID]) as 'number of donations', sum(t.[Amount Accepted]) as 'blood drawn'

FROM [DBO].[Transfusion Record] as tr JOIN  [Transfusion] as t on tr.[Transfusion ID] = t.[Transfusion ID]
group by tr.[Blood bank name]
)

SELECT CTE.[Blood bank name],  CTE.[blood drawn] - ISNULL(CTE2.[blood drawn],0) as  'blood left'
FROM CTE LEFT JOIN CTE2 on CTE.[Blood bank name] = CTE2.[Blood bank name]
```

I don't think you need to subtract the number of donations.

**Result**

```
Blood bank name                                     blood left
California Blood Center                             22
Community Blood bank                                289
Delta Blood bank                                    534
Houchin Valley Blood bank                           279
```